# Running on bones, I am shaking

Tags: riddle

Running on bones,
I am shaking.

Who or what am I?

Note:

I am visiting the Philippines now, and this is the direct translation of a popular local riddle spoken in Cebuano.

hint:

> It is a simple riddle and definitely solvable.  The answer is not something scary or obscure.  It is a common thing. It is not a living thing.  It is manmade.

Comment: Robias? I doubt that is even a word

Comment: it is a simple riddle with an English answer.

Comment: is it a wooden bridge? when you run on a wooden bridge it shakes!("bones" are the horizontal pieces of wood)

Comment: If your riddle requires a hint to be uniquely solvable, I'd advise putting the hint into the riddle itself, because as-is, it's obviously a human runner with one of a number of medical disorders causing uncontrollable movement.

Comment: I didn't include the hint into the riddle because it is a local Cebuano riddle among the natives.  I did not write this riddle, it is only a direct translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> a train?  Train tracks could be considered bone-like and trains do tend to shake

Comment: That would have been my guess too.

Comment: You are correct, congrats. +1

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. What's the original text in the native tongue?

My guess:

> A dog - a dog runs on/after bones, and shakes it's head to get them... hard to explain, more like playing fetch.

Comment: I updated the riddle with a hint.  I do not know the original native text, this is the English translation of it.

Answer (score 2):

I almost want to say...

> Dice, because you shake them to roll, and they are sometimes referred to as bones.

Comment: Good guess, but I run on bones, I am not bones.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be:

> A couple of maracas. Filled with bones and shaken to produce sounds.